# Compute the direction of the force in 3d

Tags: python, 3d, physics

I'm trying to build a 3D simulation of a solar system but i'm having difficulty in finding the 3D equivalent of this 2D python code

`# Compute the force of attraction
     f = G * self.mass * other.mass / (d**2)`

```
# Compute the direction of the force.
    theta = math.atan2(dy, dx)
    fx = math.cos(theta) * f
    fy = math.sin(theta) * f
    return fx, fy
```

Comment: I would recommend adding the Physics tag - at its heart, your  question is a math question. You need to find out how to calculate the Z component of the force vector.

Comment: @opticaliqlusion thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2-D code is ridiculously inefficient.  You don't need any trigonometry at all.  It's just multiplying the magnitude of the of the force, `f`, by a unit vector in the (dx, dy) direction.  Given that you already know the length of the vector, `d`, all you need is

```
fx, fy = f*dx/d, f*dy/d
```

In 3-D

```
fx, fy, fz = f*dx/d, f*dy/d, f*dz/d
```